# Toggle show/hide with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
( function( $ ) {

var $f = $;

$('.entry-content').hide();

$f(function(){
        $f(".entry-title" ).toggle(
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideUp('fast');
            },
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideDown('fast');
            }
        );
});

} )( jQuery );
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arete/21ada3ra/)**

Pretty basic I guess but, I would like to click on the `.entry-title` links to display the content with the `.entry-content` class. However, it seems I have to click on the link two times for the content to expand. Why is this and how can this be fixed? Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Also, is there a way to close the previously opened div when another one opens?
Sort of like an accordion.

Comment: reason to need double click is misplacement of the events try `$f(".entry-title" ).toggle(
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideDown('fast');
            },
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideUp('fast');
            }
        );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** for toggle between them.

> **[`toggle event`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9 .

```js
var $ele = $('.entry-content').hide(); // hide initially
$(".entry-title").click(function(e) { // bind click event handler
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click event handler
  var $ele1 = $(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideToggle('fast'); // toggle the animation
  $ele.not($ele1).slideUp(); // slide up remaining
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <p class="destaques-data">2010-03-10</p>
  <h3><a href="#" class="entry-title">Mauris aliquet mattis metus</a></h3>
  <p>Requerente: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/ornare/" rel="tag">Ornare</a>  <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/pede/" rel="tag">Pede</a> Localização: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/localizacao/matosinhos/" rel="tag">Matosinhos</a> Tipologia:
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/amet/" rel="tag">Amet</a>  <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/elit/" rel="tag">Elit</a>
  </p>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <p>Aliquam aliquet, est a ullamcorper condimentum, tellus nulla fringilla elit, a iaculis nulla turpis sed wisi. Fusce volutpat. Etiam sodales ante id nunc. Proin ornare dignissim lacus. Nunc porttitor nunc a sem. Sed sollicitudin velit eu magna. Aliquam
      erat volutpat. Vivamus ornare est non wisi. Proin vel quam. Vivamus egestas. Nunc tempor diam vehicula mauris. Nullam sapien eros, facilisis vel, eleifend non, auctor dapibus, pede.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p class="destaques-data">2006-11-08</p>
  <h3><a href="#" class="entry-title">Cras aliquam massa ullamcorper sapien</a></h3>
  <p>Requerente: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/enim/" rel="tag">Enim</a> Localização: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/localizacao/matosinhos/" rel="tag">Matosinhos</a> Tipologia: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/ipsum/" rel="tag">Ipsum</a>
  </p>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <p>Pellentesque vel dui sed orci faucibus iaculis. Suspendisse dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum. Nulla congue. Vivamus sit amet lorem posuere dui vulputate ornare. Phasellus mattis sollicitudin ligula. Duis dignissim felis et urna. Integer adipiscing
      congue metus. Nam pede. Etiam non wisi. Sed accumsan dolor ac augue. Pellentesque eget lectus. Aliquam nec dolor nec tellus ornare venenatis. Nullam blandit placerat sem. Curabitur quis ipsum. Mauris nisl tellus, aliquet eu, suscipit eu, ullamcorper
      quis, magna. Mauris elementum, pede at sodales vestibulum, nulla tortor congue massa, quis pellentesque odio dui id est. Cras faucibus augue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jesus! You are so fast you either have to bee writing at the speed of light or you must be an AI. Either way thanks a bunch man! Great work!

Comment: @Arete :  glad to help you :)

Comment: @Arete Adding `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` on an anchor click event within jquery can make it possible to prevent redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function like this:

```
$f(".entry-title" ).toggle(
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideDown('fast');
            },
            function() {
                $f(this).parents(".post").children('.entry-content').slideUp('fast');
            }
        );
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23koL4c1/) shows working code, it's up to you if you want to add ID's or make use of classes instead or add the code you had (something about parent-child relationship), but this is the basic to make such slide work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".entry-content").hide();
  $(".entry-title").click(function() {
    if ($(".entry-content").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".entry-content").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".entry-content").slideUp();
    }
  });
  return false;
  /* or e.preventDefault(); */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <p class="destaques-data">2010-03-10</p>
  <h3><a href="#" class="entry-title">Mauris aliquet mattis metus</a></h3>
  <p>Requerente: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/ornare/" rel="tag">Ornare</a>  <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/pede/" rel="tag">Pede</a> Localização: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/localizacao/matosinhos/" rel="tag">Matosinhos</a> Tipologia:
    <a
    href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/amet/" rel="tag">Amet</a> <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/elit/" rel="tag">Elit</a>
  </p>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <p>Aliquam aliquet, est a ullamcorper condimentum, tellus nulla fringilla elit, a iaculis nulla turpis sed wisi. Fusce volutpat. Etiam sodales ante id nunc. Proin ornare dignissim lacus. Nunc porttitor nunc a sem. Sed sollicitudin velit eu magna. Aliquam
      erat volutpat. Vivamus ornare est non wisi. Proin vel quam. Vivamus egestas. Nunc tempor diam vehicula mauris. Nullam sapien eros, facilisis vel, eleifend non, auctor dapibus, pede.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p class="destaques-data">2006-11-08</p>
  <h3><a href="#" class="entry-title">Cras aliquam massa ullamcorper sapien</a></h3>
  <p>Requerente: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/requerente/enim/" rel="tag">Enim</a> Localização: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/localizacao/matosinhos/" rel="tag">Matosinhos</a> Tipologia: <a href="http://localhost:8888/aspp/tipologia/ipsum/" rel="tag">Ipsum</a>
  </p>
  <div class="entry-content">
    <p>Pellentesque vel dui sed orci faucibus iaculis. Suspendisse dictum magna id purus tincidunt rutrum. Nulla congue. Vivamus sit amet lorem posuere dui vulputate ornare. Phasellus mattis sollicitudin ligula. Duis dignissim felis et urna. Integer adipiscing
      congue metus. Nam pede. Etiam non wisi. Sed accumsan dolor ac augue. Pellentesque eget lectus. Aliquam nec dolor nec tellus ornare venenatis. Nullam blandit placerat sem. Curabitur quis ipsum. Mauris nisl tellus, aliquet eu, suscipit eu, ullamcorper
      quis, magna. Mauris elementum, pede at sodales vestibulum, nulla tortor congue massa, quis pellentesque odio dui id est. Cras faucibus augue.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```